# What is the equation for the speed of a molecule at a specific temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, dimensional-analysis, speed, gas

What is the equation for the speed of a molecule at a specific temperature? I saw two equations $v = \sqrt{\frac{3 k T}{m}}$ and $v =\sqrt{\frac{3RT}{m}}$. What is the difference?

Comment: For ideal gases, average kinetic energy equals to $E=\frac{3}{2}kT=\frac{1}{2}mv^{2}$ where k is equal to the ideal gas constant divided by Avagadro's number $\frac{R}{N_A}$

Comment: This link may help https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45838/how-to-deduce-e-3-2kt

Answer (score 4):

The speed of a molecule at a specific temperature can be described by the root-mean-square speed equation, which is given by $v_{\text{rms}} = \sqrt{\frac{3kT}{m}}$, where $k$ is the Boltzmann constant, $T$ is the temperature in Kelvin, and $m$ is the mass of the molecule in kilograms.

The equation $v_{\text{rms}} = \sqrt{\frac{3RT}{M}}$ is another form of the root-mean-square speed, where $R$ is the universal gas constant, $T$ is the temperature in Kelvin, and $M$ is the molar mass of the gas in kilograms per mole (kg/mol).

The difference between the two equations lies in the use of $k$ instead of $R$ and $m$ instead of $M$. I think you assumed that both equations have mass $m$ in the denominator! But if you use $R$ you need to use the molar mass $M$!

Answer (score 2):

A molecule does not have a temperature, only a gas of molecules in thermal equilibrium has. The molecules in such a gas can have a wide range of speeds. The speeds obey a
[Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution) with average speed determined by $<v^2>=3kT/m$.

[image: Distribution of particle speed for 1 million oxygen particles at -100, 20 and 600 °C]

Distribution of particle speed for 1 million oxygen particles at -100, 20 and 600 °C. From [https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell–Boltzmann_statistics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_statistics).

Note on ‘oxygen particles’ added to the Wikipedia talk page:

“In the figure caption ‘oxygen particles’ are mentioned. It should be specified whether atoms, molecules, ozone or pieces of frozen oxygen  are meant. If these are not atoms, rotation and vibration come into play. If they are, what’s keeping them from forming dimers?”